# How do I remove duplicates based on not only one but two conditions from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I am trying to remove the duplicated "Box" rows based on two columns in my Dataframe:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Box': ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A5'], 'Status': ['Prep', 'Ready', 'Prep', 'Prep', 'Ready', 'Prep', 'Ready'], 'Week':[11, 12, 12, 13, 11, 10, 11], 'QTY': [6, 7, 6, 8, 5, 8, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

- if there is duplicated Box numbers, take the one with the min(Week)
- if there is duplicated Box numbers, take the Status !=Ready (not equal to ready)

What I have tried so far :

`df1= df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Week", "Box"], keep=False)`

If both conditions are met, I want to take the Status!= Ready condition as priority.

The expected result is:

[image]

Comment: Please include dataframes as text, not as images.  Also, what happens if both your conditions are met?  Which one takes priority?

Comment: added them both @user3483203

Comment: Which one gets priority overall? week or status? Because you could have a status that is not the min week.

Comment: I added that info in the question too: If both conditions are met, I want to take the Status!= Ready condition as priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataFrame.drop_duplicates(...)` defaults to keeping the first item it finds based on the subset of columns you specify.

In other words, `df.drop_duplicates('Box')` will keep the first of each unique value of `Box` and drop the rest.

So we just need to sort our data frame so that the items we want to keep are the first ones we encounter.

```
uniques = df.sort_values('Week').sort_values('Status').drop_duplicates('Box')
```

This makes quite a few assumptions:

1. Your data is small, so sorting twice like this is not too expensive.
2. That you have no other values of `Status` that might disrupt this. `Prep` happens to be lexographically before `Ready`.
3. You have no examples where a lower `Week` value has `Ready` in `Status` - because we sort by `Status` last, we place a higher priority on this condition. You can reverse them if you want to filter by `Week` first.

EDIT:

with the data you posted:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {'Box': ['A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A5'], 'Status': ['Prep', 'Ready', 'Prep', 'Prep', 'Ready', 'Prep', 'Ready'], 'Week':[11, 12, 12, 13, 11, 10, 11], 'QTY': [6, 7, 6, 8, 5, 8, 7]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> df.sort_values('Status').sort_values('Week').drop_duplicates('Box').sort_index()
  Box  QTY Status  Week
0  A1    6   Prep    11
2  A2    6   Prep    12
3  A3    8   Prep    13
4  A4    5  Ready    11
5  A5    8   Prep    10
```

For assumption 2 above, I recommend having an ordering for your statuses, then adding a column based on that.

```
order = { 'Prep' : 1, 'Ready' : 2 }
df['status_order'] = df['Status'].apply(lambda x: order[x])
```

Then you can sort by this column instead of `Status`. This generalizes to handling duplicates for non-`Ready` status.

Comment: thanks! Only issue would be the assumption #2: I may have other status conditions, and I want the one that is NOT equal to "Ready" so the alphabetic sort won't work. The rest is great, thanks so much. I just need a solution for the assumption 2 - that's all left :)

Comment: What other status do you have?

Comment: @Logan, brilliant - I accepted the answer- thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = df['Status'].unique()

df['Status'] = pd.Categorical(df['Status'], categories= np.concatenate([x[x!='Ready'], ['Ready']]), ordered= True)

df.sort_values(['Status', 'Week']).drop_duplicates(subset=["Box"]).sort_values('Box')
```

I made the status column a categorical column, then ensured ready was the largest value, by concatenating it to the unique values of status. This ensures that for the sort it will always be last.